# SQL PHP Syntax ERROR Optimisation

Tags: php, arrays, syntax, query-optimization

I get an error in this code. Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong. This is the error i get:

`Died You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1`

This is the code:

```
   $depSQL = mysql_query("SELECT department_array FROM busDetails WHERE bus_id='".$bus_id."' LIMIT 1"); 
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($depSQL)) 
   { 
     $depARRAY = $row["department_array"]; 
   }
    $stSQL = mysql_query("SELECT department_id, staff_array FROM institute_departments WHERE department_id IN ($depARRAY)") or die ("Died ".mysql_error());
   while($get=mysql_fetch_array($stSQL)) { 
   $stARRAY = $get["staff_array"];
     $id =  $get["department_id"];
   $explodedST = explode(",", $stARRAY);
  foreach ($explodedST as $key2 => $value2) {
        if ($value2 == $bus_id) {
            unset($explodedST[$key2]);
        }
}
$newST = implode(",", $explodedST);
echo $id . " " . $newST . "<BR/>" ;
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE institute_departments SET staff_array ='$newST' WHERE     department_id='$id'");
 }
```

Comment: When i echo the query i get this: `died: SELECT department_id, staff_array FROM institute_departments WHERE department_id IN (233,1,2,3,265,6,7,8,9,)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1` I'm i missing something?

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA. thanks guys. Haven't slept in a while. I think its my code. do you know how to remove the an empty array? My php code inserts in automatically. Any help would be great!! thanks again

Comment: Do you know how to remove the extra comma. Could you please have a look at my code and suggest what I could do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$strArray = explode(',' , trim($depARRAY));

$count = count($strArray);
if(empty($strArray[$count-1]))
    unset($strArray[$count-1]);

$depARRAY = implode(',' , $strArray);
```

You must take care of `extra comma` , while inserting the values.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, it doesn't work. I echoed the result before and after the `if($strArray[$count-1] == ',')
  unset($strArray[0]);` The results are the same. Do you know any other way to do it? Please help.

Comment: Hu Gaurav, it worked wonderfully!! I tried editting your code - I havent got edit privileges lol :p You made a slight mistake. Change `$cont` to `$count` ;)

Answer (score 2):

echo your queries and you'll probably see it.

Example:

```
echo $stSQL;
```

You have a comma too much. Look after the 9: "7,8,9,)

Comment: I get this error. I don't see anything wrong, do you? `died: SELECT department_id, staff_array FROM institute_departments WHERE department_id IN (233,1,2,3,265,6,7,8,9,)
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1`

Comment: You have a comma too much. Look after the 9: "7,8,9,)"

Comment: You have an extra comma ',' after 9. Remove the extra ,

Comment: HAHAHAHAHA. thanks guys. Haven't slept in a while. I think its my code. do you know how to remove the an empty array? My php code inserts in automatically. Any help would be great!! thanks again.

Comment: Do you know how to remove the extra comma. Could you please have a look at my code and suggest what I could do.